# TCP handshake scapy code not working

Tags: scapy

I am facing a problem during TCP handshake using Scapy. My Scapy code is sending SYN packet. Target is responding with SYN/ACk Packet. I could see SYN/ACK packet in tcpdump but its not receiving at scapy code. 
Note: There is no RST packet sent from linux m/c.

Here is my code snippet:

```
@ATMT.condition(IPCP_OPEN)
def send_syn(self):
    time.sleep(10)
    self.src_port = random.randrange(1024,65535)
    print "Sending SYN packet"
    print "Src MAC: "+self.mac+" dest MAC: "+DEST_MAC
    send_pkt = Ether(src=self.mac,   dst=DEST_MAC)/Dot1Q(vlan=self.vlan_out)/Dot1Q(vlan=self.vlan_in)/PPPoE(sessionid=1)/PPP(proto=IP_PROTO)/IP(src="1.0.115.34",dst="10.10.10.10")/TCP(sport=self.src_port, dport=80, flags="S")
    hexdump(send_pkt)
    print "src_port: "+src_port
    sendp(Ether(src=self.mac, dst=DEST_MAC)/Dot1Q(vlan=self.vlan_out)/Dot1Q(vlan=self.vlan_in)/PPPoE(sessionid=self.sess_id)/PPP(proto=IP_PROTO)/IP(src="1.0.115.34",dst="10.10.10.10")/TCP(sport=self.src_port, dport=80, flags="S"), iface=self.iface, verbose=False)
    # hexdump(pkt)
    raise self.WAIT_SYNACK()
```

Transitions from `WAIT_SYNACK`

```
@ATMT.receive_condition(WAIT_SYNACK)
def receive_synack(self,pkt):
if (TCP in pkt):
   print "Recvd SYN/ACK"
   hexdump(pkt)
   #self.src_port = pkt[TCP].dport
   self.seq_no = pkt[TCP].ack
   self.ack_no = pkt[TCP].seq
   print "processing SYN/ACK"
   raise self.GOT_SYNACK()
```

My `master_filter` is as follows

```
def master_filter(self, pkt):
return (PPPoED in pkt or PPPoE in pkt) and  (pkt[Dot1Q:1].vlan==self.vlan_out) and (pkt[Dot1Q:2].vlan==self.vlan_in)
```

Why my scapy code is not receiving SYN/ACK packet ?

Comment: Could you a) add information on scapy version - scapy 2.x or scapy3k; b) OS version; c) more explanation on network? Also, I would start with simple case first - e.g. just direct IP communication without PPP and Ethernet layer to check your code, and adding complexity on top of that.

Comment: Hi, Eriks, My scapy version is scapy (2.3.1) , OS version -

Comment: OS version is 
[root@bngce-sw-lnx3 ~]# uname -a
Linux bngce-sw-lnx3.englab.juniper.net 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:43 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Network is my Linux machine is connected to Juniper MX router.
MX(ge-0/0/1)  --------------     Linux M/c(eth1)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `TCP` because you're just filtering for `PPPoE*`. Change your filter to `pkt.haslayer(TCP) or (...`

```
def master_filter(self, pkt):
    return (PPPoED in pkt or PPPoE in pkt) and  (pkt[Dot1Q:1].vlan==self.vlan_out) and (pkt[Dot1Q:2].vlan==self.vlan_in)
```